# How do you get the current cursor with CursorPagination?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

By default, CursorPagination gives you the next and previous cursors. Is there a way to get the current cursor?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. The current page is the list of results. What would a cursor be doing there?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Going next cursor and back to the previous cursor would give you the "current cursor." This would be a way of saving the current position. This is different from getting the newest list of results.

Comment: But isn't that just the current URL?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No. Maybe I didn't explain it properly. Here's an example.

e.g. In the current URL, you see 5 posts [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].  A week later, there are 100 more posts. The current URL would give you [101, 102, 103, 104, 105] but you want to continue from where you left off.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand. Why would the current URL give you 101,... instead of 1,...?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Cusors point at a specific 'spot' in an ordered list of records.  If more records are added after, then your request would give you the same records as the last time you called, even if there are new records that have appeared since.  The [101, 102] are virtual positions.  That said, the question doesn't make a lot of sense, since its contrary to the purpose of a cursor.  I'm quite confused now.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Well that depends on the ordering. But regardless, since we don't have a cursor at the initial URL, there's no way to save the cursor.

Comment: Think about loading an infinite scrolling page showing newest to oldest and saving that location.

Answer (score 0):

The `CusorPagination` class simply reads the value from the querystring and decodes it for internal use.  If you want to know what the current position is for the request that was just made, you can simply do the same.  Since the paginator instance is thrown out after use, you can't peek at it.

Even if you could, you would get the 'decoded' cursor value, which you would have to re-encode to send again later.

```
# from rest_framework/pagination.py@CursorPagination.paginate_queryset
encoded = request.query_params.get(self.cursor_query_param)

# read it yourself somewhere in your view/viewset
current_value = request.query_params.get('cursor')
```

If you want to change the behavior in general, just make a custom implementation and return the additional field.  Set that as your `pagination_class` on the view (or in settings if its global).

**UNTESTED** example code:

```
class FancyCursorPagination(CusorPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('current', self.get_current_link()),
            ('results', data)
        ]))

    def get_current_link(self):
        """ 
        Return a link to the current position. 
           - self.cursor set in the paginate_queryset() method.
        To return only the query parameter in this field, use:
           - return request.query_params.get(self.cursor_query_param, None)
        """
        if self.cursor:
            return self.encode_cursor(self.cursor)
        else:
            # cursor will be None on the first call
            return None

    def get_paginated_response_schema(self, schema):
        new_schema = super().get_paginated_response_schema(schema)
        new_schema["properties"]["current"] = {
            "type": "string", 
            "nullable": True
        }
        return new_schema

class MyApiView(APIView):
    pagination_class = FancyCursorPagination
```

Comment: `self.encode_cusor(self.cursor)` will throw an error because it doesn't have an offset. If you gave it a 0 offset, it'll give you an empty cursor. You could do something like this but there are more edge cases to handle...
`Cursor(offset=0,reverse=True,position=self._get_position_from_instance(self.page[-1], self.ordering))`

Comment: Ah, i get it.  I didn't account for the first request (with no cursor given).  In that case `self.cusor` will be None.  I'll edit the question, but its still untested :D